# How to encrypt S3 bucket using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I am trying to create encrypted S3 bucket. After I execute terraform apply, it all looks good, but when I look at the bucket in the AWS Console, it's not encrypted. I am also aware of the [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47957225/sse-encryption-of-s3-using-terraform) question.

Here is my terraform version:

```
Terraform v0.11.13
+ provider.aws v2.2.0
```

Here is my tf file:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "test-tf-enc" {
  bucket = "test-tf-enc"
  acl    = "private"

  tags {
    Name = "test-tf-enc"
  }

  server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        sse_algorithm = "AES256"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the output after I execute the command:

```
aws_s3_bucket.test-tf-enc: Creating...
  acceleration_status:                                                                                   "" => "<computed>"
  acl:                                                                                                   "" => "private"
  arn:                                                                                                   "" => "<computed>"
  bucket:                                                                                                "" => "test-tf-enc"
  bucket_domain_name:                                                                                    "" => "<computed>"
  bucket_regional_domain_name:                                                                           "" => "<computed>"
  force_destroy:                                                                                         "" => "false"
  hosted_zone_id:                                                                                        "" => "<computed>"
  region:                                                                                                "" => "<computed>"
  request_payer:                                                                                         "" => "<computed>"
  server_side_encryption_configuration.#:                                                                "" => "1"
  server_side_encryption_configuration.0.rule.#:                                                         "" => "1"
  server_side_encryption_configuration.0.rule.0.apply_server_side_encryption_by_default.#:               "" => "1"
  server_side_encryption_configuration.0.rule.0.apply_server_side_encryption_by_default.0.sse_algorithm: "" => "AES256"
  tags.%:                                                                                                "" => "1"
  tags.Name:                                                                                             "" => "test-tf-enc"
  versioning.#:                                                                                          "" => "<computed>"
  website_domain:                                                                                        "" => "<computed>"
  website_endpoint:                                                                                      "" => "<computed>"
aws_s3_bucket.test-tf-enc: Still creating... (10s elapsed)
aws_s3_bucket.test-tf-enc: Creation complete after 10s (ID: test-tf-enc)

Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

Comment: The code looks good and even the terraform output looks good. It might be a bug with the latest AWS Provider. Have you tried 1.60? You can specify it like this: provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-east-1"
  version = "1.60.0"
}

Comment: the provider version is ok for this resource, and the code looks fine. So it will be something else.

Comment: I tested with aws provider version 1.60.0 to no avail.

Comment: Your terraform code looks good so it must be something else that is causing the problem, maybe a permissions issue. Try this cli command to see if it works: aws s3api put-bucket-encryption --bucket my-bucket --server-side-encryption-configuration '{"Rules": [{"ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault": {"SSEAlgorithm": "AES256"}}]}'

Comment: The code is working properly; the user I am using to log into the AWS Management Console does not have sufficient rights to view the s3 bucket encryption property. Thanks @victorm for helping me chase down the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works as expected.
Using different user without sufficient permissions to validate operation through UI in AWS Management Console resulted in the confusion. Insufficient permissions message in UI only visible after expanding the Encryption pane.
Use aws cli for troubleshooting to reduce the problem surface.

Answer (score 2):

For new versions, `server_side_encryption_configuration` is deprecated and `aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration` should be used instead:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket#enable-sse-kms-server-side-encryption

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration